# Is it ethical to offer design help for pro bono projects

Tags: discussion

Ok, guys here apparently have not much experience in UX design:

[Exhibition Audio Guide Tour: Text should be present or not](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/106567/exhibition-audio-guide-tour-text-should-be-present-or-not/106569#106569)

At the same time, it seems to be a non-profit project. Should it be so, is it okay to offer them design help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you choose to work on external to this site is up to you. If you want to do work for free then you're welcome so do so.

However, Stack Exchange is not a social network so there are no means available for one member to contact another, and posting contact details in posts is not appropriate (it will get removed if spotted and opens people up to getting spammed, plus it serves no benefit to anyone else reading the post).

If they had published contact / website details in their profile then that would be the only way to contact them.

So in summary, yes you can do work for whomever you like, but you can't use Stack Exchange features to get in contact with other members.

Comment: Thanks! I have a feeling they may go totally wrong with it, so I will be glad to help them.

Comment: Just because a company is officially a charity, that doesn't really mean they don't have money to pay people. Heck [Rolex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolex#Hans_Wilsdorf_Foundation) is a charity!

Comment: Naaah, they are just students.